# Return only post(s) which have post_excerpt

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, excerpt, rest-api

I'd like to grab a random post but only one which has a post excerpt. Is there any way that I can query this during a call to `get_posts()` or `wp_query()`?

Bonus points if I could do it with REST, I explored down that route and found myself back at `get_posts()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should work, not tested for syntax errors though

```
        function random_post() { 

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby'   => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => 1, 
            );

        $post = query_posts( $args );

        }

        if(!$post->post_excerpt){
          random_post();
        }

// Then down here you would do whatever with the $post object
```

Answer (score 1):

the following code will check whether there is a record excerpt:

```
if ( has_excerpt( $post->ID ) ) {
    // This post has excerpt
} else {
    // This post has no excerpt
}
```

The following code will return 1 record in which there excerpt:

```
function get_random_post_by_excerpt($post_type){
global $wpdb;
$id_post = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = '%s' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_excerpt != '' ORDER BY RAND();", $post_type));

return $id_post = (!empty($id_post))?$id_post:false;  
}
```

call function:

```
$post_id = get_random_post_by_excerpt('post');
```